# Is it possible to hide folders/subfolders from users based on permissions?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ntfs, file-permissions

Having a Windows Server 2008 R2 that has a share with lots of nested folders, I want to be able to only show certain folders to certain AD users/AD user groups.

Is it possible to configure the permissions on single folders, so that clients that connect with Windows XP/Windows 7 to the share on the Windows 2008 R2 server only see those folders for which they have "view" permission?

Other clients should not see the folders at all in Windows Explorer.

I was told that this seems to be a standard feature on Novell networks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's called [Access Based Enumeration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784710%28WS.10%29.aspx) since Server 2003 SP1; and [works in 2008 (and R2) too](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772681%28WS.10%29.aspx).